# How to resolve Forward reference in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Here is my mysql query.I am getting the below error.How to resolve?

```
select 
    p.P3_WOTypeId,
    p.P3_WOId,
    p3_WoNo,
    p3_wotype.P3_WOType,
    case when((
        SELECT P3_SubmissionCount
         from p3_woqmsmaster
         where p3_woqmsmaster.P3_WOID = P3_WOID
           and P3_ReviewType = P3_WOStatusDescription 
           and p.P3_WODisplay = 1
         order by P3_QMSId desc limit 1
    )) > 1
    then concat(p3_wostatusmaster.P3_WOStatusDescription,'_Rework')
    else p3_wostatusmaster.P3_WOStatusDescription
    End As P3_WOStatusDescription
from p3_womaster p
Join p3_wotype on (p3_wotype.P3_WOTypeId =  p.p3_WoTypeId)
where p.p3_WODisplay = 1
  and p.P3_workTemplateId ='19'
  and P3_WOId IN(
      select DISTINCT P3_WOId
      from p3_woqmsmaster
      where P3_SubmissionCount > 1
  )
  and p.p3_wostatusId in (2,3)
```

I am getting below error

> Error Code: 1247. Reference 'P3_WOStatusDescription' not supported
>   (forward reference in item list)  0.000 sec

How to resolve?

Comment: I think your problem is reletad with "Order By" row

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to `p3_wostatusmaster.P3_WOStatusDescription` in your `case` statement, but you never join with `p3_wostatusmaster`. Join with `p3_wostatusmaster`.

Comment: Thanks.When I joined I wand to bind '_Rework' but it is not binding.

Answer (score 0):

P3_WOStatusDescription in your case statement is referred case itself's alias as P3_WOStatusDescription, better use the full name `p3_wostatusmaster.P3_WOStatusDescription` as other reference does.

similar example

```
mysql> explain select (select a union select a) as a, 1 as b;
ERROR 1247 (42S22): Reference 'a' not supported (forward reference in item list)
```